# If I spin a magnet in a coil which has a length parallel to the magnet’s spin axis, is a magnetic field generated along the length of the coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction, conductors

This I feel is a bit of a complicated question, so I’ll quickly try to paint as clear a picture as I possibly can:

The magnet is spinning on an axis perpendicular to its poloidal axis (the line which can be drawn pole-to-pole) at the center of a coil of enameled copper wire which has a length parallel to the magnet’s spin axis.

I assume the answer to the question is yes; the spinning magnet will induce a current in the coil that’ll generate a magnetic field in the direction of the length of the coil.

If it is indeed the case that a magnetic field is generated in the direction of the length of the coil—perpendicular to the magnet’s spinning poloidal axis, parallel to its spin axis—then why do we say a conductor moving through a magnetic field has generated in it a magnetic field that “opposes” the original magnetic field? To me that seems to imply the field is generated in the same plane as the magnet’s poloidal axis (i.e. the generated field’s south pole is facing the magnet’s south pole, and is thus opposing the magnet’s field), but if the field generated in the coil is *perpendicular* to the magnet’s spinning poloidal axis (parallel to its spin axis), then how could it also be oppositional to the magnet’s field?

Comment: It would simplify your question to somehow provide a drawing if you could.

Comment: Here’s a gif that demonstrates the positions of the various components: https://media4.giphy.com/media/9aT6ZJcw3brbKFJzCu/giphy.gif?cid=2154d3d7d80f9509e22051b5ec06aa7ed43a2cfdfb9ab30a&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g

Comment: To generate a current the magnetic flux through the coil has to change, and spinning the magnet like that doesn't change the flux through the coil.

Comment: I don’t understand. Why wouldn’t it change the flux through the coil? The magnetic field is physically “brushing” the coil regardless of its orientation, and the coil is made of a conductive material. So given that a conductive material has induced in it a current when experiencing a changing magnetic field, what would cause the coil in this configuration to not have induced in it a current?

Comment: Just draw magnetic field lines for several orientations of the magnetic field, the flux doesn't have any component that is perpendicular to the area of the coil. What does change is the orientation of the field , but that is contained entirely within the plane of the coil. That is separate frome the whole induced electric field due to changing fluxes/areas.

Comment: What I don’t understand is why the radial field being contained within the plane of the coil would result in zero inductance… At the end of the day a coil is a chunk of conductive material, and as far as I can tell, when a chunk of material is in the path of a changing magnetic field, a current is induced in that material.

Comment: Just think of it this way, the induced field must resist the changing field through the coil, that is faradays law with lenzs law. However if you write down the field of a dipole magnet spinning the way you have shown, you can show the time rate change of the flux is zero. So no change in flux means the coil can't have an induced field.

Comment: @triatticus the flux does not change in a homopolar generator and it still works.

Comment: @hyportnex I am aware of such things, the motion of the electrons however in this case are different. I suppose in this case you might get something similar to an AC current.

Comment: So what I’m gathering is that this configuration may be worth investigating. I’m anticipating very little current, rather than zero. It isn’t the ideal configuration for efficiently producing current, but my goal is to generate a ‘novel’ field geometry which has a radial field about its X,Y plane and an alternating field along its Z-axis. Based on a conversation I had with someone yesterday it seems variable misalignment will provide a ‘boost’ to the current production. May play around with incorporating precession of the spin axis. If the current is DC that’ll be disappointing.